# how to change discrete node ids into continuous one?

Tags: python

I have a graph where the ids of nodes are discrete. Is there any way to make these ids continuous while keep the relationship between original nodes?
For example, I have a graph with 6 nodes and 3 edges: 1->2, 6->9, 8->7
How can I make node ids continuous such that I can have a graph with edges like: 1->2, 3->6, 5->4 where '3' refers to '6', '4' refers to '7' ,etc.

Comment: What is your actual data structure?

Comment: By "continuous" do you mean "consecutive"? Do you want the difference between two node values to remain the same under your transformation? If so, what if that is not possible due to multiple connections to the same node or for other reasons?

Comment: Also, why do you want to start with `1` and not `0`, which seems better suited for practical purposes?

Comment: Find highest used number and replace it everywhere by lowest unused number. Repeat until lowest unused is higher than highest used number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `list` of edges (`tuples`), you can use the `defaultdict` trick for continuous ids:

```
from collections import defaultdict

edges = [(1, 2), (6, 9), (8, 7), (6, 7), (9, 1)]

d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d) + 1)
id_edges = [(d[x], d[y]) for x, y in edges]
# [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (3, 6), (4, 1)]
```

Or starting at `0`:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))
id_edges = [(d[x], d[y]) for x, y in edges]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (3, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want.